# What triangles do the $p-$adic numbers generate?

Tags: number-theory, trigonometry, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory

> What triangles do the $p-$adic numbers generate?

Every pair of parameters $m>n$ of [Euclid's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) for generating unique, prime, pythagorean triples, when arranged as $x=\frac{m}{n}$ forms a unique $2-$adic rational number satisfying $x>1$ and $\lvert x\rvert_2\neq 1$.

I understand that the $2-$adics include irrrational numbers which makes me curious as to how this analog is extended into these.  A little experimentation seems to show that these generate further prime triangles, with non-integer sides.

It would seem likely the $p-$adics are closely related to various fields in which the right angled triangles are prime.

What sets of triangles do the $3-$ adic and $p-$adic numbers in general, generate?  Is this observation used to help visualise and solve problems in number theory?

Comment: The connection to 2-adics here seems very strained.  Can you explain what you mean by "A little experimentation seems to show that these generate further prime triangles, with non-integer sides"?

Comment: @EricWofsey the relation between rational p-adics and integer triangles is perfect, not strained at all. I'm not knowledgeable enough about irrational p-adics but plugging in some irrational numbers, with the prime factors partitioned into $m$ and $n$, generates triangles with irrational sides.

Comment: @EricWofsey e.g. if we take $2\cdot3^{\frac{1}{3}}$ as an example, partition its prime factors into $m=2\cdot3^{\frac{1}{3}}$ and $n=1$ then we generate the triangle having sides $4\cdot3^{\frac{2}{3}}+1, 4\cdot3^{\frac{1}{3}}, 4\cdot3^{\frac{2}{3}}-1$.